# Product attribute in Model

Tags: product-attribute, filter, modal-popup, multiselect-attribute

I have an attribute product that is a multiple select. I need to fill it with many operation options to select from, like a thousand or more.

Is there the possibility to put this multiple selection in a modal using a grid or some kind of filter so that it only shows me the selected options and use a search bar to display the options that I want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$multiSelectData = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4', 'option5'];

        $data = array(
        'attribute_set'           => 'Default',
        'group'                   => 'Autosettings',
        'type'                    => 'text',
        'backend'                 => '',
        'frontend'                => '',
        'label'                   => 'YOURATTRIBUTELABEL',
        'input'                   => 'text',
        'class'                   => '',
        'source'                  => '',
        'global'                  => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => false,
        'user_defined'            => true,
        'default'                 => '',
        'searchable'              => true,
        'filterable'              => true,
        'comparable'              => true,
        'visible_on_front'        => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique'                  => false,
        'apply_to'                => '',
        'is_used_in_grid'         => true,
        'is_visible_in_grid'      => true,
        'is_filterable_in_grid'   => true,
    );

if (!$multiSelectData === false && is_array($multiSelectData)) {
        $data['input'] = 'multiselect';
        $data['option'] = array('values' => $multiSelectData);
        $data['backend'] = 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend';
}
```

**NOTE**
Into this code, `$multiSelectData` which show as array static, you can create those array from your dynemic grid collection value. So it will show options from your customize grid.